# sp2013 foundation: Can I configure the refiners on the default search page?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, search-results

I am using SP2013 foundation. Can I configure the refiners on the default search page? When I go to the default search page I cannot edit page.

Comment: did you follow this http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/11/07/plan-to-use-refiners-on-a-search-results-page-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Comment: I try to use the refinables managed properties. This is not working. I still dont see the refiners on the left of the OOTB search results page. Anyone else?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer. No.
Create a Search centre and configure your refiners there. The OOTB ossearch.aspx page is not editable.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this blog from Bella Engen, [How to add refiners to your search results page in SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/11/11/how-to-add-refiners-to-your-search-results-page-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

**UPDATE:**

Go to the search settings page of your site and set the "Which search results page should queries be sent to?" as the search centre results page.

**OR**

If you do not want to/can't set up a custom search page in search centre, then create a webpart page in you site pages. Add the Search Box, Search Results and the Refinement Webparts to the page. Once you have the custom search page, go to the search settings page and set the property "Which search results page should queries be sent to?" as the custom search results page.

You should be able to customize the refiners for the Refinement Webpart as per you need.

Comment: That only lets you edit a results page in a search centre, @KHA asked about the default out of the box search page in a site

Comment: I have update the answer with more details on how to achieve solution for the problem. Hope this helps